# Why do these filters, one using AND and one using OR, evaluate the same in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Here is a filter using AND in Clojure:

```
(filter #(and (= 0 (mod % 3) (mod % 5))) (range 100))
```

It returns, as I would expect,

```
(0 15 30 45 60 75 90)
```

On the other hand, here is the same filter using OR instead of AND:

```
(filter #(or (= 0 (mod % 3) (mod % 5))) (range 100))
```

To me, it doesn't make sense that it would return the exact same list, but it does.  Why doesn't the list with OR return

```
(3, 5, 6, 9, 10 ...)
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `=`, it looks to see if all the parameters passed to it are equal. In each example filter checks if `0 = (mod % 3) = (mod % 5)`. Instead, check each case individually:

```
(filter #(or (= 0 (mod % 3)) (= 0 (mod % 5))) (range 100))
```

You might also consider using `zero?`. I think it makes it a little easier to read and helps in avoiding issues like this one.

```
(filter #(or (zero? (mod % 3)) (zero? (mod % 5))) (range 100))
```

Comment: @ tessellator  Thanks, that makes sense.